# jQuery multiple selector with $(this) for Drop-down and Text-field

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#sb_Height_Questionnaire_afraid_of_heights ,
    #tf_Height_Questionnaire_afraid_of_heights').on('change',function(){                  
      if ($(this[0]).val() == 'Yes' || $(this[0]).val() == 'No'){
        $("#hf_Height_Questionnaire_afraid_of_heights").val("Are you afraid of heights:" 
         + $(this[0]).val() + $(this[1]).val());
      } 
});
```

If yes or no is selected do something. onchange even both select box and text-field 
example : https://jsfiddle.net/mkhizess/s9or1c20/

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with your code please ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mkhizess/s9or1c20/

Answer (score 2):

Inside the event hadndler, `this` will refer to the changed element, not all the elements selected by the selector so `this[0]` will be undefined.

So try

```
var $els = $('#sb_Height_Questionnaire_afraid_of_heights , #tf_Height_Questionnaire_afraid_of_heights').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Yes' || $(this).val() == 'No') {
        $("#hf_Height_Questionnaire_afraid_of_heights").val("Are you afraid of heights: " + $els.eq(0).val() + $els.eq(1).val());
    }
});
```